# How can i install Tomcat, Java inside one docker container?

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. 
So as per my research, i came to know that docker is a perfect option to build our code, ship and deploy it on any platforms. 
Now my doubt is How can i install Tomcat, Java inside one container? and

Comment: obviously you (Revathy U) did not the sightless research, even using this google keywoards 'tomcat docker image' brings you the correct answer in the first hit

Answer (score 0):

Most open source projects already have images available so you don't need to reinvent the wheel. If you search [`docker <name of project>`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=docker%20tomcat) the Docker Hub image page will generally be the top result.

Tomcat is here: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/

You can see how they did the install by clicking one of the image [Dockerfile links](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/989f50ed5db788921a4954109b90362e2209295e/9.0/jre8/Dockerfile).

You can run the image with `docker run -p 8080:8080 tomcat:8` or any of the tags listed on a hub page.

Start your custom `Dockerfile` with

```
FROM tomcat:10
```

Comment: Be aware that all offical tomcat images are based one the official java images, which are openjdk and NOT oracle java. This can make a huge difference to a lot of people. So there is a valid point in installing it manually

Comment: and then get sued by Oracle! :) but seriously, since openjdk became the reference implementation are their still huge differences?

Comment: Huge huge, as it always has been